# understanding kivy code snippet

Tags: python, kivy

I am using the following code from web:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Line


class DrawInput(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        print(touch)
        with self.canvas:
            touch.ud["line"] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        print(touch)
        touch.ud["line"].points += (touch.x, touch.y)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        print("RELEASED!", touch)


class SimpleKivy4(App):
    def build(self):
        return DrawInput()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    SimpleKivy4().run()
```

Why does the method `on_touch_down(self, touch)` get implemented even when it is not being called explicitly anywhere?

Edit: If `widget` fires based on when the touch happens. Then how does the `DrawInput()` function `on_touch_down` get fired. Cause class `Widget` doesn't know about `DrawInpout()` class or any of it's methods.

Comment: It's simple inheritance. The `DrawInput` class subclasses `Widget`, which likely includes logic to run various pre-defined methods, including `on_touch_down`, `on_touch_up`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

They get called, because they are Widget class methods that you override.
They are events bound to click/touch, on the Widget.

As from the [Widget](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget) docs

> Events:
>
> on_touch_down:
>      Fired when a new touch event occurs
>
> on_touch_move:
>      Fired when an existing touch moves
>
> on_touch_up:
>      Fired when an existing touch disappears